# IOS Variable on a Variables

Tags: ios

I am trying to run a for loop to add UILabels for each row in parse and it will not display anything when there is more than one row. Is this possible and if its not what is the best approach.

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSNumberFormatter *f; // and you should reuse formatter
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    int x = 0;
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        // Title Design
        CGRect labelocation(x) = CGRectMake(40, 105+(35*x), 100, 30);
        UILabel *myLabel(x) = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelocation(x)];
        myLabel(x).text = object[@"name"];
        myLabel(x).layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255 green:170.0/255 blue:220.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor;
        myLabel(x).textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:0/255 blue:0/255 alpha:1];
        [self.view addSubview:myLabel(x)];

        //Second Amount Design
        CGRect secondAmountSize(x) = CGRectMake(141, 105+(35*x), 150, 30);
        UILabel *secondAmount(x) = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:secondAmountSize(x)];
        secondAmount(x).layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255 green:170.0/255 blue:220.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor;
        secondAmount(x).textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:0/255 blue:0/255 alpha:1];
        secondAmount(x).textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        secondAmount(x).text = object[@"startingBalance"];

        [self.view addSubview:secondAmount(x)];
        x++;
     }

}];
```

Comment: you want to add label on uitableview cell

Comment: you can use auto layout rather than calculating the label frame manually